# Handling try catch for an if statement in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
public void verifyErrorMsgforInvalidUserTransPosting(
{
String errorMSG="You dont have permission to create transaction using this ID";
String errorMSGSYS=driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/div/.....").getText();

if(errorMSGSYS.equals(errorMSG))
    {
        System.out.println("System didnt allowed user to post the Transaction");
        report.updateTestLog("Verify System is NOT allowing user to post transaction for an invalid user", "System didnt allowed user to post the Transaction", Status.SCREENSHOT);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("System is allowing user to post the Transaction which is NOT expected behavior");
        report.updateTestLog("Verify System is NOT allowing user to post transaction for an invalid user", "System is allowing user to post the Transaction which is NOT expected behavior", Status.FAIL);
    }
}
```

In the above code, if(condition 1) will work when the element is found and if the condition1 satisfies 
else statement works when there is a mismatch

Could some one help me how can i handle the else when the element is NOT found using try catch or any other method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this somthing along the lines of what you are looking for?

```
public void verifyErrorMsgforInvalidUserTransPosting(
{
    String errorMSG="You dont have permission to create transaction using this ID";
    Boolean isPresent = driver.findElements(By.xpath("html/div/.....").size() > 0;

    if(!isPresent)
    {
        System.out.println("Failed to find element");
        return;
    }

    String errorMSGSYS = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/div/.....").getText();       
    if(errorMSGSYS.equals(errorMSG))
    {
        System.out.println("System didnt allowed user to post the Transaction");
        report.updateTestLog("Verify System is NOT allowing user to post transaction for an invalid user", "System didnt allowed user to post the Transaction", Status.SCREENSHOT);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("System is allowing user to post the Transaction which is NOT expected behavior");
        report.updateTestLog("Verify System is NOT allowing user to post transaction for an invalid user", "System is allowing user to post the Transaction which is NOT expected behavior", Status.FAIL);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do things a little different. You have some strings that are repeated several places so I put them all up top. I think it makes the code easier to read. I also handled the case of ensuring that the desired element is present before checking it's text value.

```
public void verifyErrorMsgforInvalidUserTransPosting()
{
    String testDescription = "Verify System is NOT allowing user to post transaction for an invalid user";
    String expectedCondition = "System didnt allowed user to post the Transaction";
    String unexpectedCondition = "System is allowing user to post the Transaction which is NOT expected behavior";
    String errorMSG = "You dont have permission to create transaction using this ID";
    List<WebElement> error = driver.findElements(By.xpath("html/div/....."));

    if (error.isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.println("Failed to find element");
        return;
    }

    String errorMSGSYS = error.get(0).getText();
    if (errorMSGSYS.equals(errorMSG))
    {
        System.out.println(expectedCondition);
        report.updateTestLog(testDescription, expectedCondition, Status.SCREENSHOT);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(unexpectedCondition);
        report.updateTestLog(testDescription, unexpectedCondition, Status.FAIL);
    }
}
```

NOTE: I noticed that your sample XPath started with the `HTML` tag. I'm hoping you don't have code that actually does that... it's a really, really bad idea because it makes the XPath very fragile. Any change in the HTML structure will break that locator. I would suggest you look for ways to find elements much closer to the desired element without using all the relative paths.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I tried with the above code as well. This is also working for me.
My actual code doesn't start with html..This is just for reference i have mentioned. Thanks for your advice. It helps in future for me :):)

Answer (score 0):

Remember, driver.findElements() may return elements which are not currently visible too (if you have multiple pages). Hence, this may be a problem.

I would recommend the following:

```
    try
    {
      String errorMSGSYS=driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/div/.....").getText();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      //code to handle "element not found"
    }

    //normal flow as earlier
```

In this case, if element is found, your normal flow works as expected. If element is not found, findElement will throw an exception which gets caught in the catch block. You can handle the flow as requried.

Hope this helps.